# Stop re-execute fail queries from SQL Server CPU 100%

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5, cpu-usage, database-deadlocks

I have an issue with my web application, the CPU usage is 100%. I am using ASP.NET webforms and SQL Server 2008 R2. When I tried to track the long running queries by selecting from `sys.dm_exec_requests`, I found 5 queries had a lot of execution count:

- the first one is 1031651 times .
- the second one is 62472 times.

The technology I am using to query is Entity Framework and the code is like this:

```
 using (var db = new xEntities())
 {
     var item = db.PageLists
                  .Where(a => a.PageUrl == pageurl && a.Status == true)
                  .SingleOrDefault();

     if (item != null)
     {
         result = true;
     }
}
```

Another query is :

```
using (var db = new xEntities())
{
    var item = db.tblSubscribers
                 .FirstOrDefault(a => a.refid == refid);

    if (item != null)
    {
        refance = item.subid;
    }
}
```

I have an index for `refid` in table `subscriber` and for the table `Pagelist` I only have 6 rows

The CPU usage is not going under 99% .

Thank you.

Comment: You are just displaying the individual queries, which look trivial.  Are you repeatedly executing these queries because of some repeating ASP.NET call?  Can you put a break point at the EF call and see that it is getting hit a lot?

Comment: actually yes ,Those 2 queries are hit a lot from the website , I have 100 hit per minute .

Comment: Can turn on a SQL Trace?  Over 1 million queries sounds really high for only 100 per minute.  And how do you know where the CPU usage is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

After checking and reading in SQL optimization , I figure out that I have to add multiple Indexes for table 'Subscriber' and 'pageList' rather than the PK .
now its working fine and the CPU is in good situation (50% at most ) .

Thank you .